# Is there a difference between "move for move" and "move after move"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

On paper these two look the same to me but when I try to use them in the same context one always seems to convey a different meaning to the other (could just be me). Here are some examples to illustrate this:

**Example 1**

- The chess player matched her move for move.
- The chess player matched her move after move.

**Example 2**

- Move for move, the older opponent was clearly the more skilled of
  the two.
- Move after move, the older opponent was clearly the more skilled of
  the two.

I can't quite put my finger on it, but I am thinking that perhaps "move for move" indicates one opponent going and then the other going, while "move after move" is the same opponent going again and again. Is that on the right track or am I missing something here?

Comment: Chess players always alternate, no need for comment. 'Move for move' means some kind of matching *with regard to the opponent* (You pawn, I pawn. You pawn, I pawn. You knight, I knight. Or some other matchie matchie.) 'Move after move' just means some repeated playing pattern (Pat moved and sighed. Pat moved and grunted.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slight connotation in meanings between the two.

"Move for move" means matching the other person's move very competitively.
Example: Jon matched Rick move for move both equal in their gameplay.

"Move after move" implies a long drawn out game.
Example: The game went on, move after move until both people were exhausted.

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you